# Children Persist in Memory after Destroy - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `Quote` model that `has_many` `shipping_methods`.

In my `ShippingMethod` model, I have a class method `refresh_rates(quote)` where I update the shipping methods for the quote. When a shipping method record is destroyed, it is still referenced in the second callback `select_default_rate` in `Quote`. I don't understand why the deleted shipping method record is still accessible from `self.shipping_methods.to_json` in the second callback since I passed `self` to the class method in `ShippingMethod`.

Here is my `Quote` model:

```
class Quote < ApplicationRecord

     has_many :shipping_methods

    before_save :refresh_shipping_rates

    before_save :select_default_rate

    def refresh_shipping_rates
        ShippingMethod.refresh_rates(self)
    end

    def select_default_rate
        puts self.shipping_methods.to_json
        #this prints all shipping methods from ShippingMethod.refresh_rates(self) including the ones that are deleted. 
    end

end
```

`ShippingMethod` model

```
class ShippingMethod < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :quote

    def self.refresh_rates(quote)
         puts "--------------------------------------"
         puts quote.shipping_methods.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).to_json
         puts "--------------------------------------"
         quote.shipping_methods.first.destroy
         puts "--------------------------------------"
         puts quote.shipping_methods.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).to_json
         puts "--------------------------------------"

      return 
    end

end
```

Here is my console output from within the `ShippingMethod.refresh_rates` function.

```
[{"id":5791,"name":"Fixed - Flat 
Rate","price":"7.99","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:27.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:27.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5792,"name":"FedEx First 
Overnight","price":"82.91","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:46.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:46.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5793,"name":"FedEx Priority 
Overnight","price":"23.01","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:05:01.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:05:01.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5794,"name":"FedEx Standard 
Overnight","price":"22.84","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5795,"name":"FedEx 2 Day 
Am","price":"20.84","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5796,"name":"FedEx 2 
Day","price":"20.15","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:49.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:49.000Z","document_id":33550}]
--------------------------------------
  ShippingMethod Destroy (0.7ms)  DELETE FROM `shipping_methods` WHERE `shipping_methods`.`id` = 5791
  ↳ app/models/shipping_method.rb:48
--------------------------------------
[{"id":5791,"name":"Fixed - Flat 
Rate","price":"7.99","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:27.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:27.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5792,"name":"FedEx First 
Overnight","price":"82.91","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:46.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:01:46.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5793,"name":"FedEx Priority 
Overnight","price":"23.01","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:05:01.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:05:01.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5794,"name":"FedEx Standard 
Overnight","price":"22.84","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5795,"name":"FedEx 2 Day 
Am","price":"20.84","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:11.000Z","document_id":33550},{"id":5796,"name":"FedEx 2 
Day","price":"20.15","selected":null,"created_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:49.000Z","updated_at":"2019-09-06T21:12:49.000Z","document_id":33550}]
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: this is because the object `quote` already loaded its `shipping_methods` associated objects from the DB, but then another part of the code modified the persisted list of associated objects. So the in-memory cached version is out of sync. You must `self.shipping_methods.reload.to_json` to re-query the DB and get an (almost) sync version. Or you could use `mark_for_destruction` instead of `destroy`, then `self.shipping_methods.reject(&:marked_for_destruction).to_json` if you want to keep the caching and not hit the db again to reload the association.

Comment: @MrYoshiji I thought your solution was working at first but I'm still having problems. Please see my console output that I've added to the question. Thanks

Comment: @CannonMoyer Try `reload`?

Comment: @dan-klasson I would but it's all executed in a before_save action.

Comment: Yeah in `select_default_rate` you do `self.shipping_methods.reload.to_json`

Comment: In the full version of `refresh_shipping_rates` I am initializing `.new` rates if they are available. On `save` for the quote, those are saved. If I use `reload` these are overwritten. @dan-klasson

Comment: @CannonMoyer in that case you must use `quote.shipping_methods.first.mark_for_destruction` instead of `destroy` + add the `autosave: true` on the `has_many :shipping_methods` (see ActiveRecord autosave doc for more info)